# Return a value and display it in a list

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns two random words from an array when I push an html button. How can i get it to display those names in a list on the page? I am not concerned on keeping the list if there is a page refresh.

```js
var data = ['name1','name2'];


function generateName() {

    var rand = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    var rand2 = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    var space = " "; 

    return document.getElementById("displayName").innerHTML = rand + space + rand2;
}
;
```

Comment: Why not `console.log` first to be sure you're getting the right data?

Comment: i did, and i am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the displayName is a `ul` element, you can create elements `li` and append those elements to `ul` using the function `appendChild`.

```js
var data = ['name1', 'name2'];

function generateName() {

  var rand = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)],
    rand2 = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];    
    
    return [rand, rand2];
};

var display = document.getElementById("displayName");
var words = generateName();

words.forEach(function(w) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = w;
  display.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id='displayName'></ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't return a value though. The question is rather vague, so I can understand why you thought answering it like this would be good enough anyway, but it still doesn't really address the issue. All you have done was turn a sentence into two li elements.

Comment: @TravisJ the OP wrote this *How can i get it to display those names in a list on the page?*

Comment: Yes, I saw that. The question is not very clear in how to accomplish that goal though. If it is simply call the function and have it do it, then this is a good approach.

Comment: i wasn't picky on how to build the list, that is why i left it open. the function works as is, i was curious if after generateName() runs if it can put the results into a list.

Comment: i made a couple of adjustments, but this worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you get the 2 random names you can create 2 new `<li>` elements with `createElement` and then append them to a `<ul>` unordered list with `appendChild(element)`. After this I return them as an object, but this is not necessary to display the names on the screen.

```js
var data = ['name1','name2'];


function generateName() {

    var rand = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    var rand2 = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
    var space = " "; 
    
    let el1 = document.createElement('li')
    let el2 = document.createElement('li')
    el1.innerHTML = rand
    el2.innerHTML = rand2

    // Adding the names to the list
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(el1);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(el2);
    
    // Returning the 2 random names
    return {rand, rand2}
};
```

```html
<button onclick="generateName()">add names to list</button>
<ul id="list">
list:
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array of elements from the `generateName` function, and feed them into a function that returns some HTML (here using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to produce an unordered list of list items) which you can add as the HTML to any element.

```js
const data = ['name1', 'name2'];

function generateName(data) {
  const rand = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
  const rand2 = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
  return [rand, rand2];
}

function buildHTML(arr) {
  return `<ul><li>${arr.join('</li><li>')}</li></ul>`;
}

document.body.innerHTML = buildHTML(generateName(data));
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #343434;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 2px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ababab;
}
```